# How to validate a form using parent attributes with Astronomy - MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, validation, meteor

I'm new with Meteor and [Astronomy](https://github.com/jagi/meteor-astronomy) and I try to validate an object based on an attribute of parent (nested relation). I read the [Nested Validation documentation](http://astronomy.jagi.io/nested-validators), but didn't found how to validate a child object only if something (here Member.level > 1).

**Code will help to understand:**

```
Address = Astro.Class({
  name: 'Address',
  fields: {
    city: {
      type: 'string',
      // Test #1: on child object
      validator: Validators.if({
         condition: function () {
           return {parent level} >= 2;
         },
         true: Validators.maxLength(50)
      })
    }
  }
});

Member = Astro.Class({
  name: 'Member',
  field: {
    level: {
      type: 'number',
      default: 1
    },
    address: {
      type: 'object',
      default: function () {
        return {};
      },
      nested: 'Address',
      // Test #2: On parent object
      validator: Validators.if({
        condition: function() {
          // Is required ?
          return (this.level !== 1)
        },
        true: Validators.required()
      })
    }
  /***/
});
```

**The goal is:** Adress are only required (and so validate), if `Member.level > 1`.

I didn't know what use on condition function to replace `{parent level}`. I tried with `this` (only Address object), `this.parent` (null) and `parent` (Window object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owner reply to this question [on the github](https://github.com/jagi/meteor-astronomy/issues/259): 
"This problem was related with Astronomy 1.0 and I'm not creating any new features for this version"

Use Astronomy 2.0 to avoid that